# A keyword in Doxygen, which will show which entities currently using function

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am documenting my functions with doxygen . An example :

```
//!  Add the variable to String Hash Map
/*!
    Given name of the string, a new the item with this name will be add.  This function is being used from GUI when user adds a constant.
    \param variableName The name of the variable which will be added
*/
void   addVariableToStrMap(const QString& variableName);
```

For almost each function I am writing something like: `This function is being used from GUI class when user adds a constant`. General way I wrote this like; "this function is being used in function `foo` of class `A` and function `foo2` of class `B`"

Is there any keyword in doxygen like  "who or when or usage" that I can use for this case?

Comment: No, and it is because the doc need to describe how the function work, and what the function do, but not how it's curently used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Doxyfile you'll find the options `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` and `REFERENCES_RELATION`. If you set them to YES then you'll get a comma separated list of the functions which are referencing the documented function and a comma separated list of the functions which are referenced by the documented function.

Further creating a custom command might be interesting for you (see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html). You could create a custom command by adding an alias with an argument in the Doxyfile, e.g.:

```
ALIASES += who{1}="This function is being used from \1 class"
```

Then you could just write in the comment:

```
\who{GUI}
```

Which would produce the sentence "This function is being used from GUI class" in your documentation.